# Baire’s Category Theorem counterexample

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

Baire's Category Theorem states that a meager subset of a complete metric space has empty interior.

Are there examples of meager subsets of non-complete metric spaces which do not have empty interior?
In particular, are the rationals numbers as a subset of themselves an example?

Answer (score 5):

Yes they do because $\mathbb Q \setminus \{a\}$ is open and dense for each $a\in \mathbb Q$. When you take the intersection of these sets for every $a$ you get $\varnothing$, notice that this is a countable intersection since there ate countably many rationals.

Comment: Ah I see, what is $a$? just any rational number?

Comment: yup ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Use $\mathbb{Q}$ as the underlying space.  For each $G_n$, use $\mathbb{Q}-\{{q_n\}}$, where $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}$, so that the countably infinite intersection is $\emptyset$.